# How to create with 2D game engine with many objects moving periodically each at a random time interval?

Tags: design-patterns

I was asked in an SDE interview with a game design question. The interviewer wanted me to design a simple 2D game, with a lot of worms moving in a 2d grid. Each worm occupies 4 cells, and has a head. It moves in one the three directions to the next cell, and in a random time interval, say 50 ms. **The problem is how to update the grid, with many worms moving at a different speed?** I gave an answer that each worm was a thread, moving itself after its predefined time. Obviously this is a very bad answer with maybe thousands of thread interleaving. Now I am thinking the grid could update itself every 1 ms with the new occupation of each worm. This could be also resource consuming. Could anyone give a more efficient solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just give each worm a timeout as to when it will move next. Then, on each frame, you reduce that timeout by the frame time. When the timeout reaches 0, you move the worm and give it a new time out.

Comment: Better yet, you have a counter that increases on every tick/frame. Then, at the start and every time a worm moves, you calculate when the worm will move next and place that (future) event into a sorted data structure (like a priority queue). On every tick/frame, then, you just compare the counter to the head of the queue, and if it matches, you perform the corresponding actions (including calculating the next events for those entities) and remove those events from the queue after they've been processed...

Comment: Yea, this is better -- it removes the subtraction from all of the worms. Minor downside is potential for wrap around if the game goes really long.

Answer (score 0):

Your multithreaded algorithm would be obviously an huge overkill here. A single thread would be enough (unless you have to optimize for a multicore system).

So you create a list of worms. Each worm is an object that holds its current position and the knowledge about when and where it will move the next time etc.
Then you need to iterate the list of worms with some frequency and redraw only the worms that moved after the last screen/window refresh.

**One of the possible optimizations**
You can ask each worm when it's going to move the next time. Then you find out the nearest moment of time when a worm going to move. Then you start a timer that will fire at that moment (the nearest moment of time when a worm's going to move). When the timer fired refresh the screen/window  (as I described before) and repeat the algorithm.
In that case your program will do nothing (that is will save CPU cycles) between individual moves of worms. The CPU load will be minimal.